# Do laws of physics prohibit direct conversion of particles to antiparticles?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, antimatter

Can antiparticles *only* be created in [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production)? How/which laws of physics prohibit direct conversion of say an electron to a positron? A neutron to an antineutron?

I have seen a comment that it is thermodynamically impossible. True? How exactly? Any other ways it is theoretically impossible?

Comment: Changing an electron to a positron would contradict conservation of charge.

Comment: @Peter Yeah just figured that, so added about neutrons too.

Comment: The neutral $K$ meson oscillates between matter and antimatter, so what you are saying is not true in general.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It depends on the particular kind of particle. Assuming the Standard Model holds, then:

- Electrons can't convert to positrons because that would violate conservation of charge.
- Neutrons can't convert to antineutrons because that would violate conservation of baryon number.
- When permitted by conservation laws, any particle can and generally *does* convert to its antiparticle. Examples include [neutral kaons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon#Oscillation), [$D^0$ mesons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_meson#D%E2%80%93D_oscillations), and [$B^0$ mesons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E2%80%93Bbar_oscillation). Kaon oscillations in particular have been measured with exquisite sensitivity, and provide some of the strongest known constraints on physics beyond the Standard Model.
- The story for neutrinos is more complicated, but to oversimplify it a bit, we still don't know whether they can or can't convert to their antineutrinos.

Comment: It's worth noting that electrons converting to positrons would also violate conservation of lepton number.

Comment: One should add that conservation laws have come from experimental observations and are as extra axioms to pick up from the general mathematical solutions of the model those solutions that fit data and observations.

Comment: @annav conservation laws are as experimental as theoretical: Noether's theorem is the basis for the latter. Also remember the drive to avoid Bohr's proposal about non-conservation of energy in beta decay that led Fermi to postulate existence of the neutrino.

Comment: @Ruslan if it were not for the experiments, there would not be any of the known conservation laws , in my opinion. I know that the beauty of mathematics convinces many physicists that mathematics creates reality instead of mathematics models reality.

Comment: @annav experiments are just a bunch of numbers and techniques. All the logic that generalizes the patterns in these numbers and lets us declare "laws" is contained in the theory. So unless you have both experiments and theory, you won't have any laws, including those of conservation of anything.

Comment: @Ruslan  We see differently on this.  Conservation laws for money, produce, water, land  etc came long before any mathematics was really dominant.

Comment: @annav But those things *aren't* conserved.

Comment: @user76284 but of course they are, The whole economy of the first civikizations was based on these conservation laws.

Comment: Note that the excess of baryons over antibaryons in our universe suggests that baryon number is only an approximate symmetry, but we don’t know how approximate. The free neutron has a weak-decay lifetime of about $10^3$ seconds; the mean time for a free neutron-antineutron oscillation is no less than $10^8$ seconds, based on carefully looking for such oscillations and finding zero of them.

Comment: @annav See [money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation#History), [produce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture#History), [water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_well_(condenser)#History), and [land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_reclamation#Notable_instances).

Comment: @rob sure, we want to look for new physics , I do not say that the conservations laws in the data are irreversible, jut that they start with the data and some of them may be wrong  in different frames

Comment: "_Conservation laws for money, produce, water, land_"? What does that even mean??

Comment: @anna that is just silly. Conservation laws pop out of the equations as soon as you try to make any sort of science. The universe requires conservation laws to make sense. If you have any expectation of future events, you are basing it on conservation law(s).

Comment: @StianYttervik Except that they only correctly appear in mathematical models carefully selected to match experimental reality. Mathematics is the product of human imagination, and must be disciplined by experiment and observation to become physics.

Comment: @john if you jump off a cliff, can you fly or will you fall? It is impossible to live your life without having any expectations of cause and effect. This requires that the universe has some sort of  structure. That in turn has the consequence of conservation laws.

Comment: @StianYttervik Indeed. But those expectations come from observation and experiment. Mathematics codifies them, but they do not originate in the mathematics.

Comment: @JohnDoty right. Any number of mathematical theories with beautiful laws can be devised whose functional dependence has nothing to do with our present reality. Science fiction takes it a step further :)

Comment: This leaves out the most obvious example; The $\pi^0$ converts to its antiparticle every time a bell rings.

Answer (score 6):

What prohibits a particular interaction from occurring are the applicable conservation laws which must be obeyed. In your two examples:

1. The conversion of an electron to a positron would
   violate the law of conservation of charge, and would also violate conservation of lepton number, meaning the reaction $e^+\rightarrow e^-$ is forbidden.
2. The conversion of a neutron to an antineutron,
   since baryon number is not conserved, $n\rightarrow \bar n$  is also forbidden.

You'll find that other interactions are allowed only if the relevant conservation laws are obeyed.